# How do I match a JQuery selector for an element on a "new" page just loaded via click event handler?

Tags: jquery

I have a link on my home page which when clicked opens/redirects to a new page (/article).  There is some code written in my main.js to insert some data inside a div called 'article'. However, when the link is clicked on the home page, the 'article' page does load but with an empty 'article' div.

It looks like the JQuery object in question is not getting matched or recognised; $article.length returns 0 and  $article.get(0) returns undefined.

Despite going through the JQuery and expressjs documentation, I cannot find a solution to this.  I even tried doing a document.ready() inside my home page's document.ready function, assuming this might execute the relevant code when the new page's document is loaded.

**main.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#results a').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        let guid = this.dataset.guid;
        let currentArticles = JSON.parse(localStorage.currentPageArticles);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/article',
            success: function() {


                    articleToDisplay = currentArticles.filter(element => element.guid === guid);

                    try {
                        if (guid && articleToDisplay)  {
                             $(location).attr('href', '/article');
                             $(document).ready(function()  {
                                let $article = $('#article');
                                populateFeedsOnPage($article, articleToDisplay);

                                if (jQuery.inArray(guid, readArticlesGUID) === -1) {
                                    readArticlesGUID.push(guid);

                                    // Save read articles data to localStorage
                                    localStorage.readArticles += JSON.stringify(readArticlesGUID);

                                }

                             });

                        } else {
                            throw ('Unable to display the article..');
                        }

                    } catch (error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }                

                }
            });  

    });

};
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/article', (req, res) => {

    res.render('article.hbs', {
        pageTitle: 'Article view',
        pageHeading: 'Article page'
    });
});
```

$('#results a') are the links on home page that are clicked.

$('#article') is the 'div' on the article page that is to be populated on the click.

**Edit - HTML:**

**home page**

```
<div id="results" class="container">
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <a target="_self" data-guid="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/42998720" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/42998720">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/70EA/production/_100060982_giroud.jpg" alt="article image">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="h4-responsive mdb-color-text">Willian and Giroud star as Chelsea ease past Hull</h4>
            <p class="mdb-color-text">Olivier Giroud scores his first Chelsea goal as they brush aside Hull City to reach the FA Cup quarter-finals.</p>
            <p class="card-text mdb-color-text">
                <small class="text-muted">null</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**article page**

```
   <div>

        <br>

        <div id="article" class="container">


        </div>


    </div>
```

Any insight or prodding in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: give your html plz

Comment: so, id `article` is not inside id `results` ?

Comment: yes, it is on a different page

Comment: results is the div which contains the a tags that can be clicked to go to the '/article' URL.  The page at this URL contains the 'article' div that needs to be updated and is not getting matched/selected.

Comment: do you want to grab article page and display the data to home page or if home page clicked redirect to article page and send some data/parameter to article page?

Comment: the second option...redirect to article page

Comment: I meant, redirect and show some data on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is really easy to do. But I don't know why you have a lot of code there.

Is this what do you want?

main.html

```
<div id="results" class="container">
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <a target="_self" data-guid="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/42998720" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/42998720">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/70EA/production/_100060982_giroud.jpg" alt="article image">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="h4-responsive mdb-color-text">Willian and Giroud star as Chelsea ease past Hull</h4>
            <p class="mdb-color-text">Olivier Giroud scores his first Chelsea goal as they brush aside Hull City to reach the FA Cup quarter-finals.</p>
            <p class="card-text mdb-color-text">
                <small class="text-muted">null</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#results a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.pageArticle = $(this).data('guid');
        window.location='article.html';
    });
});
</script>
```

article.html

```
<div id="article" class="container"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#article').html(localStorage.pageArticle);
});
</script>
```

> **Update: server side scripting**

Still easy. This will not need our jQuery script at all.

home.html

```
<a href="article.php?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/42998720"></a>
```

**PHP**

article.php

```
<div class="article"><?=$_GET['url'];?></div>
```

**NodeJS**

app.js

```
app.get('/article', (req, res) => {

    res.render('article.hbs', {
        pageTitle: 'Article view',
        pageHeading: 'Article page,
pageUrl: req.query['url']
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks I just ended up doing this.  I thought there must be some way to achieve the same thing within one javascript (main.js) instead of having js code in both html documents.

however, now I'm repeating some functions (like, populateFeedsOnPage) in both the HTML documents.  Is there a way to access common methods in the main.js file from different html docs?

Comment: Actually, article view is 'article.hbs.'  Plus, I am to code this task in Node.js and JavaScript.  Thanks anyway though. Appreciate the help!